# how to search between two column

Tags: sql, between

Given a table with the following columns and data:

```
comment, minAge, maxAge
"a"      1       5
"b"      13      25
"c"      20      50
"d"      22
```

Is it possible to do a sql query like:

```
select * from rows where 16 to 22
```

between minAge and maxAge. With the results:

```
"b", 13, 19
"c" ,20, 50
"d" ,22
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `minAge` >= 16 AND `maxAge` <= 22
```

This would get every row where the minAge column is greater than or equal to 16 and the maxAge column is less than or equal to 22.

UPDATE

If you want to also return rows where minAge and/or maxAge is null use this.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`minAge` >= 16 || `minAge` IS NULL) AND (`maxAge` <= 22 || `maxAge` IS NULL)
```

So this query should now satisfy the row where the comment has a value of "d". Credit to Tom Lord for the suggestion.

Comment: Would this need tweaking for cases where minAge or maxAge is `null`?

Comment: Erm I don't think so from what I understand if minAge or maxAge is null then it wont fulfil the condition.

Comment: From the original question, if `minAge == 22` and `maxAge == null` then they want this result to be included.

Comment: @TomLord ah yes I see, your update to the question made the data a lot clear. I would have to agree with you. I'll update my answer to accept null values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BETWEEN Sql condition

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE column BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

You can view specific information in this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)